# Positioning elements with a background image Android

Tags: android

I need your help.
I have an image (eg http://www.gif.tv/tv.png) and I want to positioned my relative layout in the middle of it.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fbutton="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:background="@null">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:paddingLeft="29dp"
    android:paddingRight="35dp"
    android:paddingTop="70dp"
    android:paddingBottom="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/phone2">
```

The problem is that when the screen changes size, relativelayout is too big / too small.
How to make the relativelayout always amid whatever the screen size?

Comment: its because of the amount of padding you've supplied to your layout will create problems.

Comment: Use an ImageView with android:src="@drawable/phone" , not a RelativeLayout.

Comment: Why do you have two nested layouts?

Comment: I know but I do not know how to place elements on top of the image without using px

Answer (score 0):

use

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Like :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fbutton="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@null">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:paddingLeft="29dp"
    android:paddingRight="35dp"
    android:paddingTop="70dp"
    android:paddingBottom="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/phone2"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: make linearlayout as matchparent width and height

Answer (score 0):

Here's your flattened (no layout nesting!) layout, with a TextView in the middle to show some text.
You may use an ImagView or a TextView which has some compound drawables, to mix text and picture/s.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fbutton="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/tv"
    >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtContents"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Some text contents here"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

`android:layout_centerInParent="true"` centers the View in the horizontal and vertical center.

You may want to use `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` or `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` to limit the centering to only one of the sizes.

Comment: Thank you, but how to place elements not in the middle?

Comment: I thought you asked: `How to make the relativelayout always amid whatever the screen size?` Anyway... just remove the `centerInParent` attribute and use paddings and/or margins and /or the other RelativeLayout alignment attributes (i.e.: `alignParentLeft`)